# How can I capture some really small no-seeums to find out what is plaguing me?

Tags: bugs

In 2014 I moved to Alaska. After a few days there I started feeling something crawling and flying around my head and neck area.  At first I thought I was imagining things because it would only happen periodically and I couldn't see anything flying.

After several months, they got worse and they started crawling/flying on and around my face getting into my eyes. After a year the problem was so bad that I have to keep my eyes covered with sealed goggles and I sleep with a head net to keep them off my face and eyes. No matter where I go I have this problem, indoor, outdoors, home, work, shopping, driving.  These flying creatures are extremely small and very difficult for anyone to see unless the light hits them just right.  Then they appear the size of dust particles and can be hard to differentiate from dust until you notice their pattern of flight. They seem to be attracted only to me, They don't bother my wife and son even when they stand right next to me.

I tried many products, supplements and changed soaps, deodorants, etc., but nothing slows them down.  My doctor thinks I 'm experiencing phantom crawling sensations or psychological issues, but I assured him that is not the problem.

My doctor wants me to catch a  specimen to show him but I don't know how to catch what I can barely see.  These are much smaller than gnats I'm used to.  Does anyone know what these things are?  And why are they attracted to me?  **How can I catch a few so my doctor has something to work with?**

Comment: Even one of the nanomesh headnets wouldn't keep out something that small. Certainly a curious problem. I would have guessed just "floaters" in your eyes, but you wouldn't feel that on your face and neck.

Comment: To answer the *actual* question: try double-sided tape.  Put it on your clothing, including a hat.  If lots of these things are trying to get at you, a few are likely to get caught in the adhesive.

Answer (score 7):

If you can constantly feel them hitting your head and see them on your clothes, you should easily be able to get them trapped on something sticky.

Try an *adhesive bug trap* or simply some *double sided tape*.

If you need to make them more visible, how about using a very strong light source? At least dust particles can be made visible easily like this, so this should also work for any kind of insect.

Answer (score 6):

You may be allergic to dust mites.

> Dust Mite Allergy
>
> If you have allergies or asthma, a tiny creature living in your home could be making big problems for you. Although you can’t see them, you may be having an allergic reaction to them. They are dust mites and they live in many homes throughout the world.
>
> Dust mites may be the most common trigger of year-round allergies and asthma. They are on every continent except Antarctica. It may not be possible to rid your home entirely of these creatures. But there are ways in which you can lessen your allergic reactions to them.
>
> What Is a Dust Mite?
>
> A dust mite measures only about one-quarter to one-third of a millimeter. They are too small to see with your eyes alone. Under a microscope, they look like white bugs. They have eight legs, so they are not insects, but arthropods, like spiders.

[Source](http://www.aafa.org/page/dust-mite-allergy.aspx)

Note that medical tests are available to identify this allergic reaction, Skin Prick Test (SPT) & Specific IgE Blood Test

Comment: But do dust mites fly?